# Windows 10 Safe Mode Language

Tags: windows-10, language

Initially I'v installed Windows 10 Pro in my native Russian language. Now I decide to full switch on English. I do lots things in regedit, settings and cmd. 99% is ready but I still have Russian when i get on System Restore / System Recovery / Cmd from Safe Mode (where actually main section is in English). How to change it fully?

Answer (score 1):

After few weeks of trying i finally found solution.

> In short - change language in bcdedit / windows / settings / sysprep /
>   regedit and etc. won't work.
>
> You just need to replace your current winre.wim file to the one from
>   Windows that have language that you prefer.

I did it simply, download Windows 10 Pro Eng ISO and extract it. Then mount /sources/install.esd file and it creates install .wim - here you go to /Windows/System32/Recovery and cut the winre.wim file and move it to your system.

Well, it's almost done. Run cmd by admin and use command:

```
reagentc /setreimage /path C:\windows\system32\recovery
```

After that one more:

```
reagentc /enable
```

Here it is. After that i restart my laptop and go to RE in Safe Mode and it become totally on English.

Comment: Oh wow I was looking for hours for this! thanks a lot